# Hibernate envers is not auditing an @ElementCollection attribute with @Column()

Tags: hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I have a class and the objects of that class should have a list of strings as an attribute, where the list of strings should be persisted as an element collection with `@ElementCollection` and the strings maximum length should be set variable with `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")`. If I write the following lines of code, a table for attribute `someTextAttributes` is created in the database. The corresponding audit table is although not created:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class SomeObject {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
   protected  long id; 
    
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @ElementCollection
   @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
   private  List<String> someTextAttributes; 
}
```

If I remove `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")` from the code, the audit table is created. This although does not solve my problem since the maximum length of the strings in the list `someTextAttributes` should be variable.

What is wrong here? How can I achieve my requirements?

The part of my persistence.xml which regards Hibernate envers is:

```
  <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_REV"/>
  <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy"/>
  <property name="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision" value="true"/>
  <property name="org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag" value="true"/>
  <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp"
            value="true"/>
```

Comment: What is your version hibernate?  It's should be fix  from version 
5.4.0.CR1 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10201

Comment: The Hibernate version I am using is 5.2.4.Final. Hibernate is auditing entities with `@ElementCollection` correctly. Just not when its combined with a column definition (`@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT"`)